# Advanced javascript calling plugin function within function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 (function($) {
     $.fn.extend({
     clock: function(options) {
     var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        .......
        .......
        return this.each(function() {
         var prev = function() {
                console.log("hello world!");
            alert('getweather');
            };
            $('#left').click(function() {alert(342);});

      });
})(jQuery);
```

how to call the plugin functions prev and $('#left') from below code

```
 $.fn.clock().prev(); //doesn't work

 $.fn.clock('#left');   //doesn't work
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have access to functions within another functions scope from outside that function.

Comment: Also, you're not closing that self executing function correctly, nor are you passing jQuery to it, as that was probably what was intended -> `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`, then again, it looks like you just did'nt inlude the entire plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, based on the code provided. It is impossible. The function is assigned to the local variable `prev`, which is not being exposed outside the local scope in any way.

If you want to make it accessible, you need to store the function somewhere such that it won't go out of scope, and then provide some interface, typically via something like `$('my-element').clock('prev')`. [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) explains best practices for exactly this, specifically under [Plugin Methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods).

Answer (score 0):

Those are `anonymous` functions. Even if they were within your scope, you wouldn't be able to call them.

A workaround would be to trigger a `click` event on `#left`:

```
$('#left').trigger('click');
```